# Is it possible to create a System UDF in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I saw that it is possible in SQL Server 2000. I want to have a function(s) where I don't have to qualify it with an owner.

for instance  `fn_trim()` instead of `dbo.fn_trim()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following on from Joe's answer

You can create a schema for your UDFs with [`CREATE SCHEMA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx) (say "fn") so you could have `fn.trim()` rather than `dbo.fn_trim()`.

Comment: I like this. I hate work arounds but this is clean and simple.

Comment: I agree.  Very cool work around.  You could do the same thing with tables and views so that if you ever need to change one to another, your not stuck with (for example) a view called "tblTableName".  I see it being really useful only on new databases and some heavily enforced standards, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The function has to be referenced as `SchemaName.FunctionName`.

As noted in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx):

> Scalar-valued functions must be invoked by using at least the two-part name of the function.